# "lib" Prefix on Libraries

Tags: c++, c, gcc, naming-conventions

From http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html:

> Note: the library must start with the three letters `lib` and have the suffix `.a`.

Is this an operating system convention, or a `gcc`/`ar` quirk?  Xcode seems to be able to create libraries without the prefix.  What's it doing differently?

Comment: It was always my understanding that this is a naming convention that is *not* enforced by the compiler toolchain.

Comment: probably using the full path to the archive.  The lib/.a convection is used with the `-l` flag, ie. `-lXXX` looks for `libXXX.a` or `libXXX.so`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can name a library whatever you want, but if you want gcc's `-l` flag to find the right one, you need to name it the way that link describes.   For example:

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.c -lm
```

Will compile `myapp.c`, link the resulting object with `libm.a`, and output an executable called `myapp`.  These days, there might be a more complicated search path involving dynamic library names, etc., but you should get the basic idea from this example.

From the [gcc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc):

> **`-l`** *library* ...
>
> ... surrounds *library* with **`lib`** and **`.a`** and searches several directories.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the absence of a space after `-l` optional?  It seems rather inconsistent.

Comment: Those old unix guys *really* hated using the keyboard! This is one feature of the unix-style linker that I've never really seen the justification for being continued into the present. Of course, you can always provide the full path and name of the library.

Comment: @Max Don't use a space. I've seen it work and not work, but in general both -l, -L, and -I expect the path/name to come next, with no intervening space.

Comment: @Max - yeah it's optional.  You can put a space there.  But when you link against `libiberty.a`, it's kind of fun to write `-liberty`...

Comment: @Carl: Especially, if you do *not* have the liberty to name the library like you want to. :)

Comment: @Neil Those old Unix guys really _knew_ how to use the keyboard... on a 300 baud terminal!

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, I've used one of those in fact this one http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/la36.html, but I still think in this case they took things a little too far.

Comment: In fact DEC's TOPS-10 OS user interface (including the SOS editor) was perfectly (though noisily) usable on a DecWriter, with no minimalist library (or other command) names.

Comment: @n.m. You had 300 baud? You lucky dog, be glad you weren't stuck with 110! They don't call those ports `tty` for nothing.

Comment: @Mark Even I have never come across a 110 baud line. Are you claiming you have? If so, connecting what to what?

Comment: @Neil before video displays were cheap and plentiful the common interface was a Teletype: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype I had the pleasure of using one with both an HP minicomputer and a Control Data mainframe. P.S. I've used the Decwriter as well, it was a big step up.

Comment: @Mark OK, now we must wait for the 75 baud guy, who also lives in a hole in the motorway and walked uphill to school, both ways. Hey, it's my Dad - at least WRT the hole and the uphill both ways!

Comment: @Mark haha, have you ever used one of these - http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/026.html (OK, perhaps not that exact model, but not far off) - one of my strangest assignments was to write a simulator for a card punch machine on an IBM PC, so that the card punch operators could continue plying their skills when the actual hardware was discontinued.

Comment: The vital "surrounds ..." documentation is missing from `man gcc` nowadays. I'm using GCC 11.3.0 with the Nix package manager.