# ldconfig Does not Include Dynamic Library With non Standard Naming?

Tags: c++, linux, centos7, ld

I have /foo/lib64/bar.so

I could link it correctly but when I start my application, it complains:

```
myapps: error while loading shared libraries: bar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I created /etc/ld.so.conf.d/bar.conf to have

```
/foo/lib64
```

And I did try to delete the cache /etc/ld.so.cache and rebuild.

"ldconfig -v" shows that /foo/lib64 has no dynamic library:

```
/foo/lib64:
/lib:
/lib64:
       libnl.so.1 -> libnl.so.1.1.4
```

So certainly ldconfig picks up bar.conf.  If I append /foo/lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it works.

How can I fix it without renaming bar.so (or symlinking) and without appending /foo/lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Thanks in advance!

Related unresolved [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842729/ldconfig-only-links-files-starting-with-lib)

Comment: That post is pretty much resolved. The resolution is that you can't do this. It may not be a resolution you like but that's what in store.

Comment: But if fixing *the application* is an option for you, read about patchelf utility.

Comment: I agree that fixing the library name is the best option but unfortunately, it is a 3rd party library I have no control :(

Comment: @n.m. if you look at the 2nd comment of the unaccepted answer, the unaccepted answer is incorrect and according to the 2nd comment, ldconfig should be able to pick up anything .so.

Comment: The second comment in the unaccepted answer is incorrect.