# Link a static library in gcc without having to specify the 'lib' prefix

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231206/lib-prefix-on-libraries) question, gcc's `-l` command requires your library to be named libXXX.a.

Is there a way to link a static library using a different command with gcc? The goal is to avoid this lib- prefix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just pass the library as in input file like so:

```
gcc main.c yourlibrary.a -o prog
```

Comment: To elaborate, `-l` is only needed to search the library path and automatically select a library with the standard naming pattern.

Comment: Accepted because it's the simplest implementation of the solution, even though Brian McFarland's answer is great too (and he taught me something about make files).

Answer (score 5):

Like nunzio said.  Just pass it in directly as an input file.  He beat me to it, but here's a full example anyway.

mylib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void say_hi(void) 
{ 
  printf("hi\n"); 
}
```

main.c:

```
extern void say_hi(void);
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  say_hi();
  return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
main: main.c mylib.a
    gcc -o main main.c mylib.a

mylib.a: mylib.o
    ar rcs mylib.a mylib.o

mylib.o: mylib.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $^
```

I realize this assumes some background knowledge in Make.  To do the same thing w/o make, run these commands in order:

```
gcc -c -o mylib.o mylib.c
ar rcs mylib.a mylib.o
gcc -o main main.c mylib.a
```

Comment: Forgive my newbishness, but can you explain your gcc -c -o $@ $^ command?

Comment: Sure.  It's a makefile thing, not a gcc thing.  These are called automatic variables.  `$@` represents the name of the make target.  `$^` represents the prerequisites (i.e. dependencies) on the right side of the `:`.  So in this case, it's short hand for `gcc -c -o mylib.o mylib.c`.  Here it's not much use.  I wrote this more out of habit than anything.   But it's necessary for generic rules and can be useful otherwise.